# Custom comparing function for elasticsearch range query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents in elasticsearch with an indexed field "score" which can contain textual values "low", "medium" and "high" (to keep the example simple).

When I search on "medium", I want to receive both documents with "low" and "medium" score. A range query seems like a nice fit for this use case, but there seems to be no way to somehow tell elasticsearch that low < medium < high. So one solution would be to not store "low", "medium", "high", but to store 0, 1, 2 instead. Another solution would be to update my index-time analyzer to index both textual and numerical representations. Maybe there is another (better) solution that I don't know of.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: is type of the score field `keyword`?

Comment: @lolotron yes it is keyword, I think the best solution would be to use a multi-field and add a custom analyzer for the mapping to integers.

Comment: yes, it looks to me like the only option multi-fields and a custom normalizer, index score field as keyword and number